# Handling Drop down list zero index in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list which retrieves a list from database. What I need is that at least one element or just text saying "no item" is shown when page loads. There is a button on the page to call database stored procedure to populate the list. So even before that button is clicked someway text "none" etc should be visible. And, second thing is for some way to make that text or list item not usable for a user.(I have tried to set element at 0th position as "none", but that makes it such that it too will respond to selectedindexchanged event of dropdown, which i would like to avoid.That is if list has names : if user selected some name and then he selects "none", he shouldn't be able to do so...or maybe not make "none" as a list item at all... Any way to do that? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdown should be like this..It have a listitem `None` with disabled property..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem disabled="disabled">None</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Feel free to mark as answer if it satisfies you..You can do it by clicking on the Tick mark on the left of the answer,Regards...

Comment: Actually, I tried this earlier today: Used page init event to add none element, while adding relevant elements to dropdown only on page load, since page refreshes many more times, so none element is only available when i need it to be, at page init.. Thanks for the help. Your approach was definitely easier (y)